dict.txt: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process
public void removeWord(String word) {
        File myFile = new File(file);
        File tempFile = new File("temp.txt");

        try {
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(tempFile, true);
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(myFile);
            while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
                String currWord = sc.next();
                String line = sc.nextLine();
                if (!currWord.equals(word)) {
                    writer.write(currWord + " " + line + "\n");
                }
            }
            sc.close();
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();

            myFile.delete();
            File rename = new File(file);
            boolean flag = tempFile.renameTo(rename);
            if (flag) {
                System.out.println("Word Removed Sucessfully...");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Error Occured...");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Something went Wrong...");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

I working on file handling in Java. I created a file and fill with words with meaning in it. I have to delete the word with the meaning given by the user. The program runs well but I am unable to delete to original file for replacing with my tempFile. myFile.delete() gives me false.

This may be file-system dependent, but... Try closing the file (i.e., close the Scanner that reads from it) before deleting.

Further to what @Robert said, try deleting the file at the first line of your program.  Obviously this is not what you want in your program, but you can then eliminate Scanner has anything to do with this.  Also you can try myFile.canWrite() to determine if you have permission to modify the file.  If you are using Windows, perhaps a text editor has a lock on this source file.

Use try with resources for all stream handling and replace File with Path to make use of better error reporting of  Files.move - that will give you an idea of the issue, most likely another app viewing or holding lock on the file. Declaring rename is unnecessary as it is same value as myFile.
